# InvalidCastException was unhandled?

Tags: vb.net, exception, casting

```
    Dim CustID As String = txtSrchCustID.Text
    Dim FirstName As String = txtNewCustFName.Text
    Dim SecondName As String = txtNewCustSName.Text

    If CustID And FirstName And SecondName = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a term to search by")
    EndIf
```

This returns "Conversion from string "" to type 'Long' is not valid." I was wondering what the error is and how it's possible to fix it? The other questions that I've looked at were mostly to do with variables assigned incorrect types, but I think that isn't the issue. It occurs when all of the variables are empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Put Option Strict On at the top of your code or set it in your project properties and it will help you catch these types of errors.

Comment: I have done this, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do. Do you want to check of **all** of them are `""`. Then do this:

```
If string.isNullOrEmpty(CustID) and _  
    string.isNullOrEmpty(FirstName) And string.isNullOrEmpty(SecondName) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a term to search by")
    End If
```

Or do you want to check if **one** of them are `""`. Then do this:

```
If string.isNullOrEmpty(CustID) orelse _  
    string.isNullOrEmpty(FirstName) orelse string.isNullOrEmpty(SecondName) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a term to search by")
    End If
```

Comment: No problem.. @user1305482:  remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings :P

Comment: Good news! I now have enough reputation to give you an upvote! :D